# libpcap - does anyone know if it relies on any other open source?

Tags: libpcap

Doing some open source licensing checks.

Can't find the answer to this after much searching.

Looked at the includes in the source code.   Nothing stood out, but I don't have all of the windows and linux includes memorized.

does anyone know if it relies on any other open source?

Answer (score 0):

"relies on" in what sense?

For example, the process of compiling it requires [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) and either [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [Berkeley YACC](https://invisible-island.net/byacc/byacc.html), but it doesn't require them at run time.

Depending on how it's configured, libpcap may be linked with other libraries.  It'll be linked with the "system library" on UN*Xes (libc on most UN*Xes, libSystem on macOS) and with the C runtime and Windows system libraries on Windows.  It may also be linked with other libraries.